# I can't get my python turtle to work

Tags: python

Every time i put import turtle it always comes this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "C:/Users/Notandi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32\turtle.py", line 2, in <module>
    wn = turtle.Screen()
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Screen'
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: you need to show us some code at least

Comment: Not sure why people want to see code... the error is clearly at `import turtle`

Comment: You probably have a file named turtle.py in that directory.

Comment: @cricket_007 Nope, it'll be at `wn = turtle.Screen()`.

Comment: @ArtOfCode The origin of the error is importing the wrong module

Comment: @cricket_007 Indeed, but the error is originating from the assignment - that's what the stack trace is saying.

Comment: @ArtOfCode: It isn't the assignment that should change; it is the name of the file that should change.  What is inside the file is irrelevant.

Comment: @zondo Yes, I understand that. My point was that the *source* of the error is the assignment line, no matter what the *cause*.

Comment: The script that's importing the turtle module named 'turtle.py` conflicts [Python newbie problem with turtle module](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2283157)

Comment: @ArtOfCode: My point is that the code is irrelevant to the problem.  If the problem is not the code, why is the code necessary to solve the problem?

Comment: I think i screwed up now it says

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
ImportError: No module named 'turtle'

Answer (score 2):

You named a file `turtle.py`, specifically this one:

```
C:/Users/Notandi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32\turtle.py
```

so Python thinks that file is the `turtle` module. Pick a different name. (Incidentally, that seems like a weird place for you to put your files in.)

Comment: Sry this is my first question

Answer (score 0):

Ok sry, I reinstalled python and that fixed it. Sry for all the annoyance i may have caused.